# JS Last value in array is never checked when looped

Tags: javascript, arrays, modulo

I am trying to loop through an array to check whether none of the values when compared with all of the remaining values in the array return a 0 after using the modulo operation.

In effect, this should only return the primes in the array without first establishing a "isPrime?" function. It currently seems to work unless I add an errant value I want spliced at the end of the array.. that one doesn't seem to get checked?

```
function ModuloPrimes(variables) 
{
  const variables = [2,3,25,5,7,9,15,14,4];
  variables.forEach(val => 
  {                
    for(let i = 0; i < variables.length; i++)
    {
      if(variables[i] % val === 0 & variables[i] != val)
      {
         variables.splice(i,1);
         ++i;
      }
    }
  })
  return variables;
}
```

What I expect the above code to return is `variables[2,3,5,7]` but currently it returns `variables[2,3,5,7,4]` and since `4 % 2 = 0`  it should also splice 4. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: take another loop approach. mutating is with `forEach` wrong why not use `filter` instead?

Comment: The splice() method of Array instances changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

To create a new array with a segment removed and/or replaced without mutating the original array, use toSpliced(). To access part of an array without modifying it, see slice(). -- MDN.

In my experience, keeping track of where the index 'pointer' is at any given time in a loop is more trouble that it's worth. Like Nina suggests make a new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you decrease the array size you should use `variables.splice(i--,1)`.

You can also use `Array::filter()` and `Array::some()` to achieve your goal:

```js
const variables = [2,3,25,5,7,9,15,14,4];

console.log(...variables.filter(n => !variables.some(val => n % val === 0 & n != val)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong logic: when `variables.splice(i,1)` the array gets decreased in length so you should check the loop `i` again, not jump over; simply replace `++i` with `--i` will solve the problem.